# Maui Mvvm working with Observable Property Class Model, how to call a class object correctly in a method

Tags: mvvm, maui, maui-community-toolkit

Still pretty new to maui and mvvm, I'm trying to figure out of to access elements in a observable property class in a method. For example I have a login class like below:

```
 public class LoginModel 
    {

       public string Failmessage { get; set; } = string.Empty;


        public string Username { get; set; } = string.Empty;


        public string Password { get; set; } = string.Empty;

        public bool Validusername { get; set; } = true;

        public bool Vaildpassword { get; set; } = true;
  


    }
```

In my modelview I call the observable property LoginModel loginModel

```
[ObservableProperty]
        LoginModel LoginModel

        public LoginPageViewModel()
        {
           LoginModel login= new();
        }
```

I want to check the property value in a method like below but it keeps giving me errors. like Fields with [ObservableProperty] should not be directly referenced, and the generated properties should be used instead.

```
 if ((string.IsNullOrEmpty(LoginModel.Username)) || (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(LoginModel.Username)))
            {
                IsBusy = false;
                LoginModel.Validusername = false;

                return;
            }
```

Am I doing something wrong here?

I want to be able to access the element of the class in a method.

Comment: Change your class declaration to `partial`. Declare `loginModel` starting with small letter. `LoginModel` property will be generated for you by MVVM Toolkit (assuming NuGet is referenced)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code, I found that you should have used nuget [CommunityToolkit.Mvvm](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/mvvm/).

And the problem is that you didn't use `CommunityToolkit.Mvvm` correctly.

You can try to add prefix  `partial` before class `LoginPageViewModel` and declare `loginmodel` starting with small letter,then`Loginmodel` property will be generated for you by MVVM Toolkit.

You can refer to the following code:

```
public  partial class LoginPageViewModel:ObservableObject 
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    LoginModel loginmodel;


    public LoginPageViewModel() {

        //LoginModel login = new();

        Loginmodel = new LoginModel();
    }

    public  void Test() {
        if ((string.IsNullOrEmpty(Loginmodel.Username)) || (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Loginmodel.Username)))
        {
            //IsBusy = false;
            Loginmodel.Validusername = false;

            return;
        }
    }
}
```

**Update**

> now the if statement is working but when I set
> Loginmodel.Validusername = false; the view is not updating with this
> new value.

If you want the UI update automatically once changing the value of model `Loginmodel`, you also need to implement interface `INotifyPropertyChanged` for class `LoginModel`.

Please refer to the following code:

```
public  class LoginModel: INotifyPropertyChanged 
    {
        public string Failmessage { get; set; } = string.Empty;

        public string Username { get; set; } = string.Empty;


        public string Password { get; set; } = string.Empty;

        // public bool Validusername { get; set; } = true;

        // modify code as follows
        private bool _validusername;
        public bool Validusername
        {
            get => _validusername;
            set
            {
                SetProperty(ref _validusername, value);
            }
        }


        public bool Vaildpassword { get; set; } = true;


        bool SetProperty<T>(ref T storage, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            if (Object.Equals(storage, value))
                return false;

            storage = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
            return true;
        }

        protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }
```

Comment: I have a base class of  public partial class ViewModelBase : ObservableObject, I did update the LoginModel to public partial class and my constructor as you recommended. now the if statement is working but when I set Loginmodel.Validusername = false; the view is not updating with this new value.

Comment: Hi @ScottNoClue, I have updated the answer, you can check it.

Answer (score 0):

1. ViewModels are ObservableObjects, not ObservableProperties.
   They contain ObservableProperties.
2. Do not construct manually your ViewModels. Use dependency injection and register them as services.
3. For this what you call "check property value", that are actually ObservableProperties in ObservableObject, there is ObservableValidator class.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/mvvm/observablevalidator

Fix this, and ask if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

I have another solution that worked for me; from what I see, there is no need for the INotifyPropertyChanged interface:

The first part is similar to what @Jessie Zhang suggests:

```
public  partial class LoginPageViewModel : ObservableObject 
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    LoginModel loginmodel;


    public LoginPageViewModel() {

        //LoginModel login = new();

        Loginmodel = new LoginModel();
    }

    public  void Test() {
        if ((string.IsNullOrEmpty(Loginmodel.Username)) || (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Loginmodel.Username)))
        {
            //IsBusy = false;
            Loginmodel.Validusername = false;

            return;
        }
    }
}
```

However, the second part would be:

```
public partial class LoginModel : ObservableObject
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    public string failmessage;
    [ObservableProperty]
    public string username;
    [ObservableProperty]
    public string password;
    [ObservableProperty]
    public bool validusername;
    [ObservableProperty]
    public bool vaildpassword;
}
```

You might not want all the properties to be observable. In that case, you just need to remove the ObservableProperty attribute and adjust the getter and setter accordingly.